# change django-tinymce content css for various object

Tags: django, django-tinymce

How can I change content_css option in django-tinymce for various objects? I mean that when I use tinymce for model1 then content_css is model1.css and when for model2 then model2.css.
I use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that I can pass extra arguments for tiny_mce in Meta class:

```
class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'field_name': TinyMCE(mce_attrs={'content_css': "style.css"}),
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the szaman's reply, I'll try to describe the process for beginners in new versions of Django (1.9), how to add custom css files to the field named '**text**' in the **Post** model in the Django's admin

1. Change fields' type in `models.py` to HTMLField

   ```
   from tinymce.models import HTMLField

   class Post(models.Model):
       title = models.TextField(default='')
       subtitle = models.TextField(default='')
       text = HTMLField(default='')
   ```
2. In the application with the required model, add to `admin.py` file:

   ```
   @admin.register(Post)  # decorator for adding Django admin for Post
   class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       form = PostForm  # attach custom form
   ```
3. Add form's class

   ```
   from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

   class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

       class Meta:
           model = Post
           fields = '__all__' # required in Django (>=1.8)
           widgets = {
               'text': TinyMCE(mce_attrs={'content_css': ["path_to_css_file",]}),
           }
   ```